# jest unit test to mock events

Tags: unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs

I have a utility file that determines the enter key-down and triggers the click event of all the button type submit present in the document.

I need help to simulate key-down of enter key, and mock buttons with type submit so as to trigger their click.

I am using jest and enzyme for testing .

Below is the utility code :

```
const runSubmitEventListener = () => {
    document.onkeydown = (e) => {
        e = e || window.event;
        if(e.key && e.key.toLowerCase() === 'enter'){
            document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]') && document.querySelectorAll('button[type="submit"]').click();
        }
    }
}

export default{
    runSubmitEventListener
}
```

Also, have started writing the test cases for which below is the file. Please suggest further steps, as I am new to jest unit testing.

```
import events from './events';

describe('events utility', () => {
    it('should have runSubmitEventListener to be defined', () => {
        expect(events.runSubmitEventListener).toBeDefined();
    });
    it('should trigger click of button type submit on keydown enter key', () => {
        const event = new keyBoardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'enter', 'keycode': 13});
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
        // expect(events.runSubmitEventListener).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```